# Branding Settings are not returned by the Channel's List API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube's Channel's list API isn't returning brandingSettings even when requested explicitly like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id=UCJ-gg-0xws8J6PKfY6DBLzg&key=
returned this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/hqQ5f5obTKYUNURbAaBo87W-LAw\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/EEjleDhJYQadoLAXlnHS41MfcRk\"",
   "id": "UCJ-gg-0xws8J6PKfY6DBLzg"
  }
 ]
}
```

I wonder if this is a problem or will it be permanent to change?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: the specific problem is branding-settings does not return, even when the request is explicit ... as in the above example ...
would like a response from youtube support if this is temporary or will it be a new rule

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question yesterday but I figured it could be a problem/bug within google's system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality (pulling brandingSettings via API) has been down since about 1am PST Aug 28, 2018. Hopefully someone from YouTube sees this and fixes soon...

Comment: Thanks for the info...You have any document or others topics about this "issue"?

Comment: unfortunately not. Things similar to this have happened in the past and usually fixed within a day or two

Comment: Thanks for this. Couldn't figure out why my requests suddenly started not including brandingSettings.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube fixed this earlier today. Should be working now!

Comment: Yes, He came back here too. Thanks a lot